# Validate a phone number in Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-5

How would I go about validating a number in laravel.

I need the number stored in the following format 353861111111.

353 will be the prefix, and the user types in the rest. If the user types in 086, this is invalid.

Comment: Is that a typo or the number is supposed to be 12 digits?

Comment: I updated my answer, I believe that is regex you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

**You can use regex as:**

```
'phone' => 'required|regex:/(353)[0-9]{9}/'
```

This checks for the pattern with starting with `353` followed by `9` digits having values from `0-9`.

Or you can build a custom validator in boot method of `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
Validator::extend('phone_number', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)

    {
        return substr($value, 0, 3) == '353';
    });
```

This will allow you to use the phone_number validation rule anywhere in your application, so your form validation could be:

```
'phone' => 'required|numeric|phone_number|size:11'
```

In your validator extension you could also check if the `$value` is numeric and `11` characters long.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it on an older Laravel 4 project we have to update from time to time:

```
'phone' => 'required|regex:/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex expression:

```
'number' => 'required|regex:^[3][5][3][\d]{8}[\d]$'
```

Comment: This regex is completely wrong.  Eg it matches 333000000000 - wrong prefix, wrong number of characters. https://regex101.com/r/L3YBKV/1

Comment: @Don'tPanic I updated the regex. Allows only 12 integers and the first three must be 353.

Comment: No, still quite wrong. Did you test it?  `[353]` is a character class, and it means match any of those characters - so 333 still matches, or 555 or 355, etc.  `[\d]` is meaningless - a character class of a decimal number is the same as just a decimal number, or `\d`. And why specify 8 decimals followed by a decimal? You have a lot to learn about regexs, grasshopper :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Okay, I edited it again. Tested it, think it works well now.

Comment: If you want to match exactly `353`, there is no need to make patterns of the digits - that is pointless work for the matching engine.  `353` is all you need.  Other problems I described last time are still there.  How about simply `^353\d{9}$`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I suppose that would work. I'm not very advanced with regex. But thanks for the help.